# Can I tie together two cellular connections for more reliable upload speeds?

Tags: speed, load-balancing, load-balancer

I don't know that much about network engineering (hence why I'm here) so please bear with me, or point me to somewhere else where I can get help.  I want to be able to broadcast a high quality video live-stream, and I need *reliable* 10Mbps upload speeds.  The only options where I live are really expensive Ethernet over fiber lines ($600+).  I have been thinking about using a cellular network, since Verizon can deliver 10Mbps upload speeds in my area, but from what I've read and observed, that number isn't at all reliable.

Here is my question: is it possible to tie together two cellular hotspots with a hardware load balancer?  Would this even work, and if so, would it give a more reliable and/or faster connection?

Comment: Did the answer help you? You should accept it if it helped you in any way. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load blancing, correctly configured, will only use a single link per flow. Spreading a single flow across links will give you out of order packet delivery, which is death to real-time protocols.

Load balancing really only works correctly if you have multiple flows, then each flow is assigned a single link, but you use the aggregate bandwidth because you have multiple flows.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks for the help!  Do you know of any cellular internet service with guaranteed speeds?

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, as they are on SE sites, except [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se]. it is rather the nature of wireless communications to have variable bandwidth.